# Why if I filter (WHERE=) a row to be equal to a value then in the results I get different values?

Tags: ms-access

I made a view in IBM, then I linked my ms-access 2003 to that view and made a query like this:

```
select * from my_view where a="hey"
```

but in the results I get a="hey" as well a="asd"

What may I do?

Comment: provide some more detail like table structure that might be helpful otherwise query looks clean

Comment: the only difference from the original is the name of the view, the field and the value. there is only on where clause no "OR" and no ORDER..

Comment: Is a the actual name of a column? Any chance your column name is a reserved word in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes in literal SQL strings.

```
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE a = 'hey'
```